# Pull specific values from a csv file and put them to another file using python

Tags: python

I am trying to pull all pin values through regex from a csv file using python into another csv file. New file should contain only pin vallues. My regex is ":"\w{17}"".

Sample data looks as below (Main file is huge with multiple pin values)-

""payload"": ""{""allocationWeek"":""2039"",""vehicleStatus"":""ORDER SENT TO PLANT"",""pin"":""PFDBW7883PKA25813"",""pnaCode"":""86002""}"","

I have tried below code so far-

```
import re
data= open(r"/Users/sj4/Downloads/python_work/Rabbiterror.csv","r").read()
#print(data)
match = re.findall("\:\"\w{17}",data)
for i in match:
    print(re.finall("\w{17}",i))
```

In this case O/P in the new csv file should be a row with value PFDBW7883PKA25813

Comment: Are PIN codes always 17-characters long in your data? Can they vary in length? If they're fixed length then code in answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If just want to pull out all the 17-character pin values then just need minor tweak to the regexp.

```python
import re
import io

contents = '''
""payload"": ""{""allocationWeek"":""2039"",""vehicleStatus"":""ORDER SENT TO PLANT"",""pin"":""PFDBW7883PKA25813"",""pnaCode"":""86002""}"","
""payload"": ""{""allocationWeek"":""1234"",""vehicleStatus"":""ORDER SENT TO PLANT"",""pin"":""PFDBW1234PKA12345"",""pnaCode"":""12345""}"","
'''
data = io.StringIO(contents).read()
for i in re.findall(r'""pin"":""(\w{17})""', data):
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
PFDBW7883PKA25813
PFDBW1234PKA12345
```

If expect only one pin per line then could iterate over the file one line at a time.

```python
for line in io.StringIO(contents):
    m = re.search(r'""pin"":""(\w{17})""', line)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```